# Sending structure to a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, structure

I'm learning how to use threads and from what I understand and from what I've read I'm doing everything right(obviously I'm not). The program compiles and gives no errors, although it seems like the threads are not being created.

I have a header file with all the includes and the structure. I want to keep the program as it is(main sending to another function the structure and creating the threads on that function)

Here is the code I've come so far:

Thread

```
void * print_data(void *arg){
    Vector *data= (Vector*)arg;

    printf("THREAD\n");
    printf("Number: %d\n",data->number);
    printf("Name: %s\n",data->name);
    printf("Address: %s\n", data->address);
    printf("\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

Function that creates/calls the threads

```
void fills_vector(Vector *dados){
    pthread_t threads[VECSIZE];
    int i, s;

    for(i = 0; i < VECSIZE; i++){

        printf("Creating thread %d...\n", i);

        s = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_data, (void*)data+i);

        if(s < 0){
            perror("Error creating the thread");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

Main

```
int main(void){
    Vector data[VECSIZE];

        data[0].number=1; data[0].name="João" ; data[0].address="Rua A";
        data[1].number=2; data[1].name="Ana" ; data[1].address="Rua B";
        data[2].number=3; data[2].name="Pedro" ; data[2].address="Rua C";
        data[3].number=4; data[3].name="Clara" ; data[3].address="Rua D";
        data[4].number=5; data[4].name="Manuel" ; data[4].address="Rua E";

    fills_vector(data);

    return 0;
}
```

With the structure being

```
typedef struct Vector{

    int number;
    char *name;
    char *address;

} Vector;
```

and VECSIZE = 5

What am I doing wrong?? The threads don't even print the first line but it gives no error creating them.

If you need any more info feel free to ask and thanks in advance

Comment: `(void*)data+i` This cast is fishy. First of all, arithmetic on void pointers is not allowed in standard C, so your compiler is (mis)configured to use non-standard extensions. And there is no need for the cast in the first place! If you added this cast to sate the compiler, you might be using a C++ compiler to compile C code, which is a very bad idea. Overall you need to look over your tool chain, seems you have some problems there.

Comment: I changed to this
(void*)&data[i]

Is this in some way better?

As I stated under I'm using Oracle VM VirtuaBox with Porteus. I use Geany to edit

Comment: Well, it is not a bug any longer, but it still doesn't make any sense. You don't need the cast at all. Your compiler is apparently GCC, compile the code as shown in the answer by Kerrek.

Comment: From what my teacher explained us the cast is so the compiler gives no warnings.

I already changed my Makefile to what Kerrek told! And as you can see it gives me no warnings whatsoever: http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/jUz0yTK.png

Comment: Your teacher is confused, the cast is superfluous. In would have been needed in C++ but not in C.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the main() function is not waiting for the threads to finish.
You need some syncronization mechanism.
You could fix it by calling pthread_join in fills_vector after creating all the threads.

Comment: Ok that worked!! Just one more question related to this, if I do the pthread_join right after the thread creation(not waiting for all threads creation) I would be stopping the program on that point right?

Thanks for the help mate!!

Answer (score 2):

Change `(void*)data+i` to `(void*)(data+i)`.

The former is ill-formed (there's no pointer arithmetic on void pointers), and if your compiler lets you get away with it, then a) you've not taught your compiler to behave well and it's wasting your time, and b) you'll probably end up with something you didn't mean.

Upshot: It pays to use a high-quality compiler that helps *you* understand C better. Examples of good compilers:

```
gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11
clang -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11
```

Comment: I understand why the change on (data+i). It keeps behaving like no thread is created.

I was only using the -Wall, but even with all those flags it gives me no errors!

I can get it to work if I send the structure from the main, but not from the fill_vector fuction. I've been searching through the answers and I can't seem to find an answer to why it's not at least showing the first print from the thread...

Comment: @AimForNuts: That can't be true. There is no void pointer arithmetic in C, and if your compiler doesn't catch that, then it's not set up correctly. [Demo](https://ideone.com/FUupzn)

Comment: I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox with Porteus and it gives me no errors...
And with @Santiago Regojo fix everything works just fine.

But how would you do it? Because I'm learning this now and that's how I'm learning :S